# Does the Lutron Maestro C.L Dimmer Exist?

Tags: electrical, led

Lutron offers a family of "C•L" model dimmers (for use with dimmable CFL/LEDs) which includes the Maestro product line:  http://www.lutron.com/EDUCATION-TRAINING/LCE/Pages/DimmingCFLsandLEDs.aspx#credenza

According to the [Maestro product line page](http://www.lutron.com/Products/StandAloneControls/Dimmers-Switches/MaestroDimmerSwitch/Pages/ModelNumbers.aspx) the applicable model numbers are MACL-153M, MACL-153MH.

Does this product actually exist?  I have been unable to find any trace of it anywhere except the Lutron site.  You can't even buy it direct from the Lutron store.

Comment: The Lutron website was just recently updated to preface references to the Maestro C.L dimmer with "COMING SOON."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give it about a month and it will be out.  Our company just had a meeting with our Lutron representative and it should be out real soon.  He did not give a date but I think they were waiting for [Lightfair](http://www.lightfair.com/lightfair/V40/) to make it official.

**EDIT**
I talked with the factory rep today and he said orders (on distributors level) are being accepted now and the C•L should be available for consumers in July.

Comment: I used to be a factory rep for Lutron many years ago. They are a great company and always on cutting edge of lighting controls. Expensive stuff, but an engineer's dream.

Comment: Fantastic, I'll keep watch for it.  I have a number of other Maestro components and would like to keep everything coordinated.

Comment: @sherlock homes  I did factory training in 89 & 04.  I thought the first trip was great but the second blew me away.  They are a great company.  Now they are concentrating on energy savings more than just summing.

Comment: @roken - Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke with Lutron technical support this afternoon. I can confirm what lqlarry wrote. The person I spoke with told me that this switch will be available in 2-3 weeks and that it will be at Lowe's and Home Depot first, then at other stores a few weeks later. I plan to watch their websites and order it when it becomes available. If anyone is looking for a Lutron Maestro IR (remote controlled) switch that is compatible with dimmable CFL/LEDs, the representative told me that they don't have a product coming out yet and that he did not know when/if it is coming out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are available. I ordered some from this site:
http://www.dimmers.net/maestro-cfl-led-dimmers.asp

I've been waiting for these to come out since my whole house is Meastro.